# Почему бот на Aiogram не отправляет фото по запросу?

Tags: python, aiogram

````
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text in groups, state=None)
async def handle_group_selection(message: Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    selected_group[user_id] = message.text  # Установите выбранную группу для пользователя

    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
    days_buttons = days.copy()

    if selected_group[user_id] in saturday_groups:
        days_buttons.append("Суббота")  # Append "Суббота" to the list

    days_buttons.append(back_button.text)
    markup.add(*days_buttons)

    await message.answer(f"Выберите день недели для группы {selected_group[user_id]}:", reply_markup=markup)


# Handler for any day of the week
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text in days, state=States.DAY_SELECTED)
async def handle_day_selection(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        selected_group = data.get('group')

    if selected_group:
        selected_day[user_id] = message.text

        # Extract the day name from the selected day (e.g., "Понедельник")
        selected_day_name = message.text
        # Replace spaces with underscores and make it lowercase
        selected_day_name = selected_day_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()

        # Construct the image file name in the format "ТБД-11_Понедельник.jpg"
        image_filename = f"{selected_group}_{selected_day_name}.jpg"

        # Check if the image file exists
        image_path = os.path.join(schedule_images_folder, image_filename)

        if os.path.isfile(image_path):
            # If the image file exists, send it
            with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
                await message.answer_photo(InputFile(image_file), caption=f"Расписание для группы {selected_group} на {message.text}:")
        else:
            await message.answer(f"Фото для данного дня не найдено. ({image_filename})")
    else:
        await message.answer("Пожалуйста, выберите группу сначала." ```
````

Comment: Бот должен искать фото из папки на пк по заданным параметрам а именно пользователь выбирает группу а потом нажимает на день недели и после этого фото должно прийти пользователю но при нажатии на день недели ничего не происходит и никаких ошибок нет.